# How to write sublists to a text file line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
boleta.write(str(list(chunks(carrito, 3))))
```

I am using this code to create sublist of 3 element each one but I need to write the sublist line by line not all in one line.

What I have:

```
[[1, '001', 40], [1, '002', 20]]
```

What I need:

```
[1, '001', 40]
[1, '002', 20]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not convert the entire result to a list and then convert that to a string, you should *iterate* through the output, and convert each *individual* sublist to a string. Like:

```
for sublist in chunks(carrito, 3):
    boleta.write(str(sublist))
    boleta.write('\n')
```

Or you could `'\n'.join(..)` the outputs together and then write the resulting string, like:

```
boleta.write('\n'.join(str(subl) for subl in chunks(carrito, 3)))
```

On some systems `'\n'` is not the line separator. You can make the program more universal by using `os.linesep`:

```
from os import linesep

boleta.write(linesep.join(str(subl) for subl in chunks(carrito, 3)))
```